# Joda Time - Parse milliseconds of a day to LocalTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a simple task: parse milliseconds of a day to `LocalTime` which will represent certain time in a day. I was thinking about that:

```
int averageLeavingMillis = 73123961 // 20:18:xx.xxx
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(new Long(averageLeavingMillis))
```

But when I print `localTime` I receive: `21:18:43.961` what is one hour more that I was expecting. Am I missing something with time zones? Or how should I convert milliseconds of a day to LocalTime?

Thanks,
Mateo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTimeZone.UTC` in cinstructor

```
int averageLeavingMillis = 73123961;     
LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(new Long(averageLeavingMillis), DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(lt);
```

Output

```
20:18:43.961
```